# Check is control assigned

Tags: delphi

I have function that contains TMemo passed in parameter. In case it is not null I would like to add some lines in it. How to check it is not null?

```
function send(logger: TMemo): boolean;
begin
if (logger <> NULL) then logger.Lines.Add('aaaa'); //not works

end;
```

Comment: `if Assigned(Logger) then` or `if logger <> nil then`

Answer (score 4):

NULL is a Variant type. In Pascal the C concept of NULL is called NIL.

So the proper way is to compare with NIL - not NULL:

```
if (logger <> NIL) then logger.Lines.Add('aaaa');
```

alternatively, and in my opinion better as it more correctly describes what you are attempting to do, is:

```
if Assigned(logger) then logger.Lines.Add('aaaa');
```